# How to make code block get a new line in Overleaf?

Tags: latex

I connot make my code block get a new line, as image
[after compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtXh.png)

It's my code

```
\makeatletter
\newif\if@restonecol
\makeatother
\let\algorithm\relax
\let\endalgorithm\relax
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}%[ruled,vlined]{
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}} 
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\caption{trace column}  
\LinesNumbered  
\KwIn{
$v$:当前访问的节点\newline
$c$:当前访问节点所要溯源的列
}
\KwOut{
$S$ :遍历所找到的根节点的集合
}  
\textbf{Initialize} $S=\emptyset$ \;
\If{$v$ instanceof DataSourceNode}{
$n$.used=false\;
$n$.id=$v$.id\;
$n$.column=position of $c$ in $v$\;
$S=S\cup \{n\}$\;
}
\ElseIf{node instanceof JoinTreeNode}{
prenode[0]=node.input1\;
prenode[1]=node.input2\;
\For{i=0;i<2;i++}{
\If{$c$ is from prenode[i]}{
$S=S\cup trace$(prenode[i],position of $c$ in prenode[i])\;
\If{position of $c$ in prenode[i]=position of key in prenode[i]}{
$S=S\cup trace$(prenode[1-i],position of $c$ in prenode[1-i])\;
break\;
}
break\;
}
}
}
return $S$\newline
\end{algorithm} 

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{trace column22}  
....as the same code block....
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

I tried to insert`\newline` and `\par` and it's useless.
Or could I create a new file and number the algorithm block from 2?

By the way, how to format code in Overleaf?

Comment: Can you make a compilable example that reproduces the problem (including a documentclass) and state where exactly you want to add a line break?

Comment: sorry, i cant embed the image, the link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtXh.png] could reflect the problem

Comment: Can you update your post with a complete, minimal example that replicates the problem? We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Also, for future reference, it's better to post these all-(La)TeX questions on [tex.se].

Answer (score 0):

By using \hfil, you will add new line immediate after the end of algorithm .

if you want to add text in the new page immediate after the end of the algorithm. then you will use the \break.